# How to associate a button to a random image in a div (3 images)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new at coding and I have a school project where we work with JavaScript and jQuery. I can't figure out how to associate a random image to an onclick event and have that image appear in a div. Basically it's a fake dating site and once you press submit it generates a random image from 3 images I have and appears in a div. Please help I'm lost here.

```
  function randomImg1() {
    var myImage1 = new Array();
    myImage1[0] = "Bush.jpg";
    myImage1[1] = "RiffRaff.jpg";
    myImage1[2] = "FredPellerin.jpg";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImage1.length);
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" 
      + myImage1[random] + "' alt='image'></img>";
  }
```

Comment: Can  include `html` at Question ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `onclick` attribute at `button` element with `randomImg1()` as value

```js
  function randomImg1() {
    var myImage1 = new Array();
    myImage1[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics";// "Bush.jpg";
    myImage1[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature";// "RiffRaff.jpg";
    myImage1[2] = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports";// "FredPellerin.jpg";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImage1.length);
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" 
      + myImage1[random] + "' alt='image'></img>";
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="randomImg1()">click</button>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with jQuery

```js
function randomImg1() {
    var myImage1 = new Array();
    myImage1[0] = "http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg";
    myImage1[1] = "http://kiteandrolltarifa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Fotos-de-surf-en-Mentawai-Surflimitmag3.jpg";
    myImage1[2] = "http://iceradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Michel-Bourez-surf.jpg";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImage1.length);
    return myImage1[random];
}

$(".random").click(function(){
    var randomImage = randomImg1();
    $("#image").html("<img src='"+ randomImage +"' alt='image'/>");
});
```

```css
#image {
  width: 200px;
}

#image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="random">Change picture</button>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without needing jQuery.

Here is a fiddle for you: **https://jsfiddle.net/5arrkmsh/2/**

It has the `onclick` on the button and reuses the same image.  You only need to change the `src` attribute.  You don't need jQuery either.  And the images are in a `div` like you specified.  Here is a snippet of the code but go to the fiddle to see it all in action.

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
  An image in a DIV<br>
  <img id="myImage" src="https://img.memecdn.com/programming_o_1075452.webp">
</div>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="randomImg1()" value="-------> Click Me! <--------">
```

JavaScript

```
window.randomImg1 = function() {
    var myImage1 = new Array();
    myImage1[0] = "http://img.memecdn.com/tis-true-be-a-relic_o_5450031.webp";
    myImage1[1] = "http://img.memecdn.com/dogs-vs-cats_c_6446431.webp";
    myImage1[2] = "http://img.memecdn.com/troll-batman_c_3026843.webp";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImage1.length);
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = myImage1[random];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Extend jQuery function
jQuery.fn.random = function() {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
  return jQuery(this[randomIndex]);
};

function insertRandomImage(targetElementId) {
  var imagesNames = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png'];

  var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';
  var imageTemplate = '<img class="image" src="%data%"/>';

  var formatedImage = imageTemplate.replace('%data%', baseUrl + imagesNames[imagesNames.random()]);

  $(targetElementId).html(formatedImage);
}

$('#eventTriggerElement').on('click', insertRandomImage('#targetElementID'));
```

`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )` Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. http://api.jquery.com/on/

`.click([eventData], handler)` This method is a shortcut for `.on('click', handler)`, but I personaly prefer `.on()` because it make my code clean and consistent for all eventing binding. https://api.jquery.com/click/